# Session not working on GAE server, only locally

Tags: java, google-app-engine, session

I have a google app engine (Java) project where I'm trying to use sessions. In my appengine-web.xml file I have

```
<sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>
```

. Then I have a UserEndpoint class that has a API method called "login". If the user that's trying to login to my app is legit I create a session like this inside my method:

```
HttpSession session = req.getSession();
session.setAttribute("userId", new LongBean(user.getId().longValue()));
```

the LongBean object is serializable and looks like:

```
public class LongBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8041280664162299553L;

    private long longValue;

    public LongBean(long longValue) {
        this.longValue = longValue;
    }

    public long getLongValue() {
        return longValue;
    }

    public void setLongValue(long longValue) {
        this.longValue = longValue;
    }
}
```

. Now, I have another API method in my endpoint called insertScore. There I check if the session is not null and has the correct "userId" attribute. The signature for that method is:

```
public UserScore insertScore(
        HttpServletRequest req,
        Score score) throws NotFoundException, ForbiddenException
```

and then I do

```
Object userId = req.getSession().getAttribute("userId");
```

. My problem is that the userId object is null when the project is deployed on google's servers. What makes this more infuriating is that it works perfectly locally. I've searched stackoverflow for my issue and the only answers I've found is that the session has to be serializable but my LongBean object is seralizable! Could anyone explain why it works on my localhost but not on my server?

Edit: extra info: I can see in the datastore viewer that a session is created and inserted into the _ah_SESSION table in my datastore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding

```
auth = @ApiAuth(allowCookieAuth = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE)
```

to my @API annotation in my endpoint allows the JSESSIONID cookie to be sent over the wire, thus fixing my issue.